# Save 3.3V + 5V short circuit

Tags: gpio, boot-issues, rip

I am very new to Raspberry Pi, and I believe I may have accidentally shorted my 3.3V GPIO pin by connecting it to the 5V one, while using a multimeter. My Pi won't boot and only shows a red light when given power. Also, connecting devices to 3.3V won't work. Is there any way to save it, or any company that can help me repair it?

Comment: a repair would probably cost more than a replacement